# struts2 jquery auto complete load all results on focus

Tags: struts2, jquery-ui-autocomplete

I am using the struts2 jquery plugin. I need to implement the auto complete functionality in such a way that when the user focuses on the auto complete element, it should display all the possible options. Also if the user enters some text, sutocomplete should be triggered.
Currently, the autocomplete gets triggerred only when text is typed . Is there any way to trigger it on focus of the element?

Answer (score 1):

1. try use `loadMinimumCount = 0`, it could help.
2. if (1) is not working, try:

   ```
   <sj:autocompleter id="test" name="test" list="list" onFocusTopics="showList"/>


   <script>
       $(function(){
         $.subscribe('showList', function(event, data){
         $('select#testjson').show();
         // or $('select[name="test"]').show();
         // try one of both.
         }
       });
   </script>
   ```